# Como sumar dos fechas de tipo date con jquey

Tags: jquery, html5

Tengo un input de tipo date lo que quiero es que tome esa fecha y le sume 30 dias a otro input date 
La verdad he buscado mucho y no he encontrado la solución

```html
<input type="Date" id="FechaI" class="form-control" name="FechaI"/>
<input type="Date" id="FechaF" class="form-control" name="FechaF" />
```

Answer (score 1):

En javascript existen varias librerías que te ayudarían a realizar lo que estas buscando, sin embargo, he creado un script para poder explicarte que es lo que se debe hacer para sumarle la cantidad de días deseados.

1. Primero debes agregar una función que detecte cuando el valor del primer campo cambie `$fecha1.change(function() {} );`
2. Dentro de la función **change** debemos convertir el valor de la fecha1 **dt1** de tipo **String** a tipo **Date**. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);`
3. Luego que tenemos la fecha1 **dt1** en tipo **Date**, procedemos a agregarle los días requeridos y utilizar el valor para crear una nueva fecha.
4. Obtenida la fecha2 **dt2**, obtenemos el año, mes y día con las funciones `getFullYear(), getMonth(), getDate()`
5. Tomar en consideración que el mes cuenta de 0 a 11, por lo que deberás sumarle uno para obtener el mes que deseas.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $fecha1 = $('#FechaI')
     ,$fecha2 = $('#FechaF')
        ,dias = 30;
  
  $fecha1.change(function() {

    var pattern = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})/
           ,dt1 = new Date(this.value.replace(pattern,'$1,$2,$3'))
           ,dt2 = new Date(dt1.setDate(dt1.getDate() + dias));
console.log(this.value.replace(pattern,'$1-$2-$3'));
    $fecha2.val(dt2.getFullYear() + '-' + (dt2.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dt2.getDate() );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="Date" id="FechaI" class="form-control" name="FechaI"/>
<input type="Date" id="FechaF" class="form-control" name="FechaF" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Deduzco que tienes asignada las fechas; pero si no, podrías utilizar lo siguiente.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
var now = new Date();                                                         
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

$('#FechaI').val(today);
$('#FechaF').val(today); //incluso, puedes sumarle los 30 días acá.

    $('#FechaI').change(function(){        
      testClicked();        
    });
});
```

Ahora para el evento change se hará de forma similar. Pero antes puedes sumarle los 30 días llamando el método `getDate()` para obtener el día de la fecha seleccionada. Por úlitmo, le asignas el valor convertido al input *FechaF* con el método `val();`

```
function testClicked()
{
var fechai = $('#FechaI').val();
var currentDate = new Date(fechai);
var day = currentDate.getDate() + 30; 
                         
var now  = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),day ); 
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
$('#FechaF').val(today);
}
```